# How to get part of a string?

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$s = '<div data-x="0" data-y="0">Some text asdasdas</div>
<div data-x="0" data-y="-1000">Some text...</div>
<div data-x="0" data-y="-2000">Some text foobar</div>
<div data-x="500" data-y="-3000">Some t..</div>';
```

The string can be different. Divs can include classes and etc.

How to get value from **data-x** and **data-y** of each Div?
Like:

```
$x1 = 0; $y1 = 0;
$x2 = 0; $y2 = -1000;
$x3 = 0; $y3 = -2000;
$x4 = 500; $y4 = -4000;
```

I would like to explode the string into an array, but then I don't know what to do ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a proper HTML parser for this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $s );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
// xpath query: find all div nodes having a data-x and data-y attribute
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//div[@data-x and @data-y]' );
$result = array();
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    $result[] = array(
        'x' => (int) $node->getAttribute( 'data-x' ),
        'y' => (int) $node->getAttribute( 'data-y' ),
    );
}
```

If you truly want `$x<n>` and `$y<n>` style variables (where `<n>` represents a number) as a result (in stead of an array of results), then you could replace the `foreach` loop with something like:

```
for( $n = 1; $n <= $nodes->length; $n++ )
{
    ${'x' . $n} = (int) $node->getAttribute( 'data-x' );
    ${'y' . $n} = (int) $node->getAttribute( 'data-y' );
}
```

I would still recommend collecting them in an array in stead though; makes for much easier processing afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This function might be useful :

`int strpos ( string $haystack , string $needle )`
*Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack string.*

You can then use [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to convert your string to an array and then get the values you need starting from a specified positions.

You can use a while loop for getting all values between `"` and the next occurence of `"` starting at the position returned by `strpos()`.

Comment: Yeah, but there can be specified classes. Or length of the data-x can be long.